# /wp-admin/ – this link showing me “Index of /wp-admin”/ instead of dashboard

Tags: wp-admin, wp-error

My WordPress site’s dashboard isn’t loading. It’s showing “Index of /wp-admin/“.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like your site's not using `index.php` as the directory index file (or else maybe `index.php` is missing). You will probably need to ask your hosting provider's support team about this.